# How can I check that the firewall is disabled for a TUN/TAP interface?

Tags: firewall, openvpn, debian-jessie

while trying to diagnose a UDP multcast issue on an OpenVPN client configuration and I've come across this block in the config file:

```
# Use the same setting as you are using on
# the server.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
;dev tap
dev tun
```

UFW does not seem to be installed (the `ufw` command is not found).  What else should I check in order to ensure that this condition is met?  Is my router's NAT configuration relevant?

Many thanks,
blz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display IPv4 firewall rules:

- `iptables -L -nv` - look at input chain,
- `iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT` - this will change firewall policy to accept all packets,
- `iptables -F INPUT` - flushing (deleting) all rules from the INPUT chain.

IPv6:
Same parameters different command, instead `iptables` use `ip6tables`.

The above will ensure that packet filtering won't touch your traffic.